# How to filter dataframe for consecutively increasing values

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a large dataframe with several columns but for this query Im interested in 3 columns.

```
df <- structure(list(country = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "ireland", class = "factor"), 
    parameter = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L,2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("rainfall", "temp", "wind"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(10L, 15L, 20L, 9L, 18L, 10L, 12L, 25L, 15L, 10L, 10L, 20L), unit = structure(c(3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
    2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("km/hr", "mm", "oC"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))

country parameter   value   unit
ireland temp          10    oC
ireland rainfall      15    mm
ireland wind          20    km/hr
ireland temp           9    oC
ireland rainfall      18    mm
ireland wind          10    km/hr
ireland temp          12    oC
ireland rainfall      25    mm
ireland wind          15    km/hr
ireland temp          10    oC
ireland rainfall      10    mm
ireland wind          20    km/hr
```

I want to group by country and parameter to extract rows where the value column consecutively increase 3 or more times.

Example of desire output.

```
country parameter   value   unit
ireland rainfall      15    mm
ireland rainfall      18    mm
ireland rainfall      25    mm
ireland wind          10    km/hr
ireland wind          15    km/hr
ireland wind          20    km/hr
```

Comment: `diff()` provides the difference between one value and the next on the list. Perhaps a check for `diff(df) > 3`? After you `sort(df, decreasing=TRUE)`, of course.

Comment: Why do you have for `wind` last 20? There are two 20 values, so the diff is zero. Is correct to have 20 there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R option using `subset` + `ave` + `rle`

```
subset(
  df[with(df,order(country, parameter)), ],
  !!ave(value, country, parameter, FUN = function(x) with(rle(cumsum(c(1, diff(x) <= 0))), rep(lengths >= 3, lengths)))
)
```

which gives

```
   country parameter value  unit
2  ireland  rainfall    15    mm
5  ireland  rainfall    18    mm
8  ireland  rainfall    25    mm
6  ireland      wind    10 km/hr
9  ireland      wind    15 km/hr
12 ireland      wind    20 km/hr
```

Answer (score 2):

You can group by country and parameter and them create a third grouping variable for values that aren't less than the lagged value, then filter group sizes 3 or larger:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(country, parameter) %>%
  group_by(x = cumsum(value <= lag(value, default = FALSE)), .add = TRUE) %>%
  filter(n() >= 3) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(country, parameter) %>%
  select(-x)

# A tibble: 6 x 4
  country parameter value unit 
  <fct>   <fct>     <int> <fct>
1 ireland rainfall     15 mm   
2 ireland rainfall     18 mm   
3 ireland rainfall     25 mm   
4 ireland wind         10 km/hr
5 ireland wind         15 km/hr
6 ireland wind         20 km/hr
```

Comment: This looks great but its not working correctly against my actual dataframe and Im not sure why. Ive tried converting my columns to factors and intergers. Using different column group by combinations. I even just brought it back to group by parameter only. The results returned include the drops after consecutive increase.

Comment: Within the country and parameter groups, it will return all instances of 3 or more consecutively increasing values.  Do you only want the first set of these values?  it's not clear from your post.

Comment: If values keep increasing yes. If there is a drop I dont want it reported. I want values that go like 1,2,3,4,5 not 1,2,3,1,1,2,1. Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: Yes, but what about  1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2 - what would you want returned in this case? Do you want 1,2,3 because it's the first set of consecutive increasing values, or 1,2,3,4 because it's the longest, or both?

Comment: Both. But in the current form Im getting: (directly from the output in my df) 7,16, 30, 10, 1, 7,13, 15, 30......  The 10 should have filtered out?

Comment: Can you edit your post and add some data that reproduces this result?

Answer (score 0):

```
df %>% 
  group_by(country, parameter) %>% 
  mutate(
    flag = c(0, diff(value)) > 0,
    flag_lag = lead(flag),
    seq_end = flag == TRUE & flag_lag %in% c(NA, FALSE),
    seq_begin = flag == FALSE & flag_lag == TRUE,
  ) %>%
  slice(if(length(which(seq_begin == TRUE):which(seq_end == TRUE)) >= 3) which(seq_begin == TRUE):which(seq_end == TRUE) else NA) %>%
  select(-contains("flag"), -contains("seq"))
```

Comment: `lag()` is more `mutate`-friendly, as you won't have to manually assign the first value.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution using `dplyr`

```r
df %>%
  arrange(value,decreasing = FALSE) %>% # Arrange by value
  filter(lag(value) > 3) # And filter for a difference above 3 in value

df
   country parameter value  unit
1  ireland      temp    10    oC
2  ireland      wind    10 km/hr
3  ireland      temp    10    oC
4  ireland  rainfall    10    mm
5  ireland      temp    12    oC
6  ireland  rainfall    15    mm
7  ireland      wind    15 km/hr
8  ireland  rainfall    18    mm
9  ireland      wind    20 km/hr
10 ireland      wind    20 km/hr
11 ireland  rainfall    25    mm
```